# Copy and paste cells with python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to copy cells value from one workbook to another. I need to copy cells A1,A2,B4,B5,B6,B7 from Sheet2 and paste into new workbook in cells A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1.
How can I do this with python?

```
import xlrd
file_location = "C:/attach/Source.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)

for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 1)
print(cell.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The process goes like this:

- open the workbook to read from with xlrd as your code does already
- create a new workbook with `xlwt`: `wb = xlwt.Workbook()`
- create a new sheet in the new workbook: `ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')`
- copy your cells to the new sheet: `ws.write(row, col, value)`

You probably want to use a dictionary to map the cell position transform. It would look like this: `{(row,col):(new_row, new_col), ...}`

To copy the cells in an existing workbook, you can use `xlutils.copy.copy()` to copy the existing workbook and put it in a xlwt.Workbook object that you can then edit. The [xlutils documentation](http://xlutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/copy.html) describes this.

Comment: What if I want to copy into an existing workbook, instead of creating a new one?

Comment: For that, you can use `xlutils.copy.copy()` to copy the existing workbook and put it in a `xlwt.Workbook` object that you can then edit. http://xlutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/copy.html